# copy a directory from a remote system to a USB drive replace a hardware image and then copy the directory back sounds simple enough

Tags: powershell, remote-server, copy-item

Thought this would be simple but.. i'm not a programmer im just trying to make something more efficient than having to re-type command after command on 20 systems mistakes happen.

so what im trying to do is copy a directory from a remote system to a USB drive replace a hardware image and then copy the directory back sounds simple enough I think it may be a double hop issue but I am lacking in how to fix it I am using a Domain Admin acccount and running powershell as administrator.

```
Clear #Clear Screen

$USBDrive = read-host -prompt "Drive letter for USB Drive?" #Get Drive Letter for EXT Media
cd $USBDrive':'                                             #Change to external media drive
$BGM = read-host -prompt "# of BGM's?"                      #QTY of BGM's


# Create copies of Convertor Files

DO{ 
    Write-Host BGM# $BGM
    Test-Path \\172.16.10.$BGM"\c$\Program Files\Box Tech\BoxManager Version 3.7\172.16.10."$BGM"_cvtrdata"

New-item \App0$BGM -itemType Directory
Copy-Item -path \\172.16.10.$BGM"\c$\Program Files\Box Tech\BoxManager Version 3.7\172.16.10."$BGM"_cvtrdata" -destination \\App0$BGM\ -Recurse
    $BGM = $BGM - 1

}
WHILE($BGM -gt 0)
```

Test-Path returns that it directory does not exist, Test-Path \172.16.10.$BGM"\c$\Program Files\Box Tech\BoxManager Version 3.7\172.16.10."$BGM"_cvtrdata"
If I use the exact path it returns true in test-path Test-Path "\172.16.10.1\c$\Program Files\Box Tech\BoxManager Version 3.7\172.16.10.1_cvtrdata"

but the copy fails I wold even be happy using robocopy to copy the files.

Comment: Also to note that the server running the script is 2008R2 and the the file being copied is on 2003